# Meaning of "secret toast" in above context?

Tags: meaning

Below lines are taken from Games of Throne Season 1 Episode 1 at time - 38:00

> Soon you will cross the narrow sea and take back your father's throne.
>       People drink secret toast to your health.
>       They cry out from their true king.

Can you please explain the meaning of secret toast in above context?

Comment: When asking about the meaning of a word., you should list the definitions that you find in your dictionary.  I found this: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/toast_1  Second sense "lifting a glass and drinking when you want someone to be happy or successful"

Comment: Sounds a bit like the Scottish practice of drinking the Loyal Toast, a customary toast to the monarch on formal occasions, while holding the glass over a bowl of water, that is, toasting the "King over the water" (Charles Stuart, exiled in France).

Answer (score 3):

"Drinking a toast" is when people say positive words, normally raise the glass, and then drink.  This is common at formal dinners but people may also do it informally.

By saying "secret toast" they mean that this is done in secret. It's equivalent to "People drink a toast to your health in secret"

Answer (score 1):

> **[toast](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toast)** (n): 2. an act of proposing or of drinking in honor of a toast

Viserys is telling Daenerys that people, **in secret**, toast her health as the rightful queen of Westeros.  They do this in secret because they are afraid of being accused of treason to the current ruler.